Aleph and beth sequence fixed points
I am new to set theory and I am not really used to math formatting on this website so I'll try my best to explain what I mean.
Hopefully somebody can edit my question to make it more clear.
I know that the Aleph and Beth functions are normal and there exists a proper class of fixed points for each function, but how can you construct them ?
For example if we let n(0) be omega and
(n+1) be aleph of the previous result then the supremum of this w-indexed sequence is the first aleph fixed point.
My question is how do we construct the next fixed point after this, do we change the indexing sequence to be w1 or do we start with w1 and similarly construct another fundamental sequence of length w.
I hope this was clear
Please feel free to edit my question !

One formulation of the fixed-point theorem is that for a normal class-function $f:\operatorname{Ord}\to\operatorname{Ord}$ we have the identity $\sup_{n\in\omega} f^n(\alpha)=\min{x\in\operatorname{Ord},:, f(x)=x\land x\ge\alpha}$. So to find the next one you can start with $\text{(last fixed point)}+1$, but equivalently you can start with $f(\text{(last fixed point)}+1)$. In general you can't start with $f(\text{(last fixed point)}+1)+1$, see the case of $f=id$.
